# Android Camera fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

I have a simple fragment that allows the user to take a picture, save it to their gallery and output it in an imageView. It works fine when I just run it as an activity but when I converted it to a fragment then the image doesn't appear in the image view, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Home.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class Home extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private final int CAMERA_RESULT = 1;

private final String Tag = getClass().getName();

Button button1;

ImageView imageView1;

@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    button1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    imageView1 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();

    if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

        Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Camera is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }   }



@Override

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.i(Tag, "Receive the camera result");

    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {

        File out = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "newImage.jpg");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),

                "Image captured and stored successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)

                .show();

        if(!out.exists()) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),

                    "Error while capturing image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)

                    .show();

            return;

        }

        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(out.getAbsolutePath());

        imageView1.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

    }

}



@Override

public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    imageView1 = null;

}

}
```

**MyFileContentProvider class**

```
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyFileContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.example.camerademo/");

private static final HashMap<String, String> MIME_TYPES = new HashMap<String, String>();

static {

    MIME_TYPES.put(".jpg", "image/jpeg");

    MIME_TYPES.put(".jpeg", "image/jpeg");

}

@Override

public boolean onCreate() {

    try {

        File mFile = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "newImage.jpg");

        if(!mFile.exists()) {

            mFile.createNewFile();

        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI, null);

        return (true);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;

    }

}

@Override

public String getType(Uri uri) {

    String path = uri.toString();

    for (String extension : MIME_TYPES.keySet()) {

        if (path.endsWith(extension)) {

            return (MIME_TYPES.get(extension));

        }

    }

    return (null);

}

@Override

public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)

        throws FileNotFoundException {

    File f = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "newImage.jpg");

    if (f.exists()) {

        return (ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,

                ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE));

    }

    throw new FileNotFoundException(uri.getPath());

}

@Override

public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projection, String selection,

                    String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {

    throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");

}

@Override

public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {

    throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");

}

@Override

public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where,

                  String[] whereArgs) {

    throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");

}

@Override

public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {

    throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, silly mistake that I didn't notice, was using the wrong package name in the contentProvider

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.example.camerademo/");